# Export a set of svg image tags as a single png

Tags: d3.js, svg

Followed the tutorial here http://techslides.com/save-svg-as-an-image

The problem is that my svg is a set of `<image>` tags, I'm trying to stitch them together and export as a full png/pdf, was wondering if that's possible

All I get at the moment is a ~1.7 mb file thats a blank image

EDIT:
Heres a sample of the svg I'm trying to export

```
<svg width="11342.5" height="320" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g width="11342.5" height="320">
     <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="source1" width="336" height="320" x="0" y="0"></image>
     <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="source2" width="336" height="320" x="0" y="0"></image>
     ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: `my svg is a set of tags, I'm trying to stitch them together`, isn't all svg a "set of tags"?  What does that mean?  More than one SVG?  Update your question with the SVG you are trying to export.

Comment: @Mark edited the question with the svg, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The impression you give from your sample is that you think SVGs work like HTML.  That you place a series of elements in the file and the renderer lays them out for you.  That is not the case.  In SVG you have to position elements yourself.

For example, all your `<image>` elements are stacked on top of one another.  That's because they are all positioned at (0,0).  You need to set the X position of each image to the right hand edge of the previous one.  For example:

```
<image width="336" height="320" x="0" y="0"/>
<image width="336" height="320" x="336" y="0"/>
<image width="336" height="320" x="672" y="0"/>
..etc..
```

Some other issues with your file:

1. Your images have a width of 336, but your SVG width (11342.5) is not a multiple of 336. Why is that?
2. The `<g>` element does not have `width` and `height` attributes. You might as well remove them.
3. Your image link `xlink:href="source1"` looks wrong.  It should probably be something like `xlink:href="source1.jpg"` etc.  Make sure those URLs are correct, otherwise you will either get blank images or the "broken image" icon (depending on the browser).
4. You don't need to define the `xlink` namespace in every `<image>` tag.  Move the `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` to the `<svg>` element.  And you can leave it out of the `<image>` elements.